# Aliasing an exported module in TypeScript for RequireJS

Tags: typescript, module, requirejs, alias, definition

I currently have several JavaScript files which I am attempting to port to TypeScript.  While I have found several ways to duplicate what I need, there is one that I cannot quite figure out from the provided documentation.

Our scripts are typically (and I use that term loosely), modules which start with something along the lines of:

```
define('mymodule', ['dependency1', 'dependency2'], function (dep1, dep2) {
   // all the guts in here.
});
```

Now, I have read (after the fact) that we probably shouldn't provide that first parameter to the define() call, but we did and then set up our requireJS configuration to specify all those module names and their paths.

Is there any way in TypeScript which I can export my module's name or alias it such a way that I can specify the first parameter to the define so that it can correctly be resolved in the RequireJS catalog?  I've tried variations of this:

```
export module MyNewModule as "mymodule" { }
```

Attempts to do this have not found a way I can do this yet and I'd prefer to let the TypeScript language generate the define() for me than doing it myself.

If there is not a way to do this then I guess I'll just take my licks for having added those to the define() statement and start doing things the TypeScript way during the migration.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it was a bit of a search, but I finally managed to come up with the answer for this.  Apparently there are triple-slash comment directives that can be used to do this.

I used the following at the top of my JavaScript file:

```
/// <amd-module name="mymodule" />
```

This added the first parameter of "mymodule" to the define() generated for jQuery, so now the output is pretty much spot on to what I need.  I did forget to mention we are currently using version 1.85 of TypeScript and we will soon be migrating to 2.3 (when we upgrade to Visual Studio 2017).  Hopefully this doesn't break when that happens.